# How to keep track of entities when a queue gets closed when modeling supermarket checkout counter in Rockwell Arena?

Tags: simulation, queuing, arena-simulation

I'm working on a simulation project with Arena Rockwell Simulation that aims to analyze the waiting queue in a supermarket and reduce the waiting time.

I have 5 checkout counters and the cashiers(=resources) are assigned in a schedule. Before the entities enter the process module(=checkout counters, seize-delay-release) they run through a decision module that

1. checks which checkout counter is open
2. if there are resources available in case the service level (4 people waiting in line) of the open counters are reached
3. names a tie breaker (the smallest check out counter number).

So far so good.

My problem now is that cashiers also have breaks. Let's say there are 4 people waiting in line at check out counter # 2 and the cashier has according to his/her schedule a break now. Then no matter which schedule rule I choose (wait, preempt, ignore) the cashier cashes at the most the current customer up. So the other 3 people are just being left in the model until the break is over and the cashier returns.

Is there any possible adjustment I can make in the model that allows the cashier to cash up the whole waiting line?

I would be very grateful for any advice!

Comment: Few points might improve the question. First use formatting for the list of actions of the decision module. Second, in a real supermarket the cashier would not leave the till while there is a queue standing. Instead she would put a sign to stop new customers entering the queue. You can probably model that by closing the counter in two stages. First close the queue, then close the counter when there are no customers left.

Comment: Even if the cashier does not take new customers, they must take all customers up until they put the sign up. In other words, it is possible that at the moment they get the signal that now is their break time, they still have to process 3 clients, after putting the sign up, only then can they take their break. Is there a way that the cashier can count how many people are waiting at the moment they get their break "event", then for every remaining customer that counter decreases by one, and they only go for a break when the counter is 0?

Comment: Can you share your *.doe file with me because I have a similar scenario and I would like to get your help. my email is: `mz.nozary@gmail.com`. Thanks